# Use an http right frame instead of https on Login page

Tags: http, iframe

I wish to use an http right frame instead of https for my login page.

However, it shows me,  unable to do so as the website is http.

Is there a way to add our right frame on the login page?

Answer (score 0):

At this point due to security reasons I don't think SFDC will allow you to Iframe with http .This is something worth checking with salesforce support that they make exception for you .